# Relationship between Bernoulli numbers of first and second type

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

I am interested in an expresion that allows to calculate Bernoulli numbers of the first kind $B_n$ from the values of the Bernoulli numbers of the second kind $b_n$ (also known as Cauchy numbers of the first kind, reciprocal logarithm numbers or gregory coefficients).

Comment: I always choose Bernoulli numbers randomly.

Comment: no problem for you then...